# Why is python-vlc playing a video in its native resolution (not fullscreen) even though I set fullscreen to True? This is on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, libvlc, python-vlc

I'm running on

```
Raspberry Pi 4 B
Python 3.11.2
python-vlc 3.0.20123
```

The video opens in the left corner of the screen without the frames of a window, but not in fullscreen. I'm not using any GUI library like `PyQT5`, just the native vlc player.

I initialize the player like so:

```
MEDIA_PLAYER = vlc.MediaPlayer()
```

How can this be fixed? I've used hours on this, trying many different solutions, but without any luck. Then again, I didn't find a post matching this behaviour, so no wonder the solutions didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to create an instance of `libvlc` with the flag `--no-xlib`, as follows:

```
instance = vlc.Instance("--no-xlib")
MEDIA_PLAYER = instance.media_player_new()
```

I'm not sure why this works. I got the idea from an example of the usage of `python-vlc` for `gtk`: https://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob;f=examples/gtkvlc.py;h=bafb442fd76db1584e1e933c7191399fa40937e8;hb=HEAD

The relevant lines are

```
48 # Create a single vlc.Instance() to be shared by (possible) multiple players.
49 if 'linux' in sys.platform:
50     # Inform libvlc that Xlib is not initialized for threads
51     instance = vlc.Instance("--no-xlib")
52 else:
53     instance = vlc.Instance()
```

Comment: You worked on this for 9 hours, but came up with the solution *immediately* after posting the question?  Impressive!

Comment: Why 9 hours specifically? Either way, answering your own question is encouraged: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ This article is linked to on the 'Ask Question' page, at the bottom. I had a hard time finding the answer, and I hope other people won't have it as bad.